# Tips on my LIFO java code

Tags: java, beginner

I've been trying to learn java recently and I finally finish my first code. Any suggestions on where I can improve? Also, is it possible to send an argument to a class using something like an **init** function in python and are there any good and bad habits that I should keep in mind?

```
class LIFO {
    
    //Create an empty list with the lenght of the given size
    //Initialize our top value as 0
    int my_list[] = new int[5];
    int top = 0;
    
    //Adds a value to the list
    //Add one to our top
    public void push(int data)
    {
        my_list[top] = data;
        top++;
    }
    
    //Removes the top value from the list
    //Substract one from our top
    public int pop()
    {
        int data;
        top--;
        data = my_list[top];
        my_list[top] = 0;
        return data;

    }

    //Prints our list
    public void show()
    {
        for(int n : my_list)
        {
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
    }
}

//Driver Class
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LIFO s = new LIFO();
        s.push(1);
        s.push(2);
        s.push(3);
        s.show();
        System.out.println("\n" + s.pop() + " Popped from stack");
        s.show();
    

    }
}
```

Comment: Title says LILO, code says LIFO, which one is it?

Comment: Oh my mistake, it's suppose to be Last In First Out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a constructor.

```
class LIFO {
    
    //Create an empty list with the lenght of the given size
    //Initialize our top value as 0
    int my_list[];
    int top = 0;

    public LIFO(int size) {
        my_list = new int[size];
    }
...
```

Call like so.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LIFO lifo = new LIFO(10);
    lifo.push(10);
    lifo.push(20);
    System.out.println(lifo.pop());
    System.out.println(lifo.pop());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I though it would be super different from python lol.

Answer (score 4):

@Ted Brownlow has answered your constructor question, but here's a few other points to consider going forward...

## Consider your class interface

Your class needs to present an interface that is functional,usable and focused.  At the moment, your class is responsible for both implementing a LIFO and outputting them to the console.  These are really different concerns.  Consider if instead of writing to the console you wanted to write to a web page / different window.  Building the display logic straight into the class makes it less flexible.  A good exercise might be to remove the `show` method and decide what method(s) you would need to add to your class in order to allow it to be implemented from outside the class.

## Bounds checking

At the moment your class has a fixed maximum size of 5.  However, other than by reading the class there's no way for the client to know (possibly missing a `maxSize` method or similar).  There's also no way for the client to know how many items are in the list, unless they keep track of it themselves (possibly missing a `currentSize` method or similar).

Without this size information, there's no way for the client to know if it's safe to call `push` or `pop`.  Consider what would happen if you already had 5 items when `push` was called.  What would happen if 0 items were present and pop was called?  At the moment, you're relying on the framework to handle these scenarios.  This can be ok, if it's a conscious decision, but you probably want to consider  adding some bounds checks and throwing exceptions that more explicitly help the user of your class know what they did wrong.

Comment: While I absolutely support thinking about edge cases, I don't support the "exceptions that more explicitly help the user" approach. Exceptions are meant for situations where a method can't fulfill its contract, and specifying exception types and situations makes exceptions part of the contract.

Comment: Thank you, those are really good points. I'll keep them in mind when writing code for now on.